# what does cvs update actually do in version control flow?

Tags: version-control, cvs

Assume there are two PC  PC_A and PC_B and a cvs repository.
PC_A and PC_B have the same code as in repo. 
Now I wrote some code on PC_A and check in ,then I cvs diff on PC_B ,it says no difference and the code is old.But it will change when I do cvs udpate?
My question is why `cvs update` exist and what really cvs update do ?

Comment: To compare your repo against your working directory without updating, try `cvs rdiff`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will attempt to update your working directory. If you don't want that, create a branch.

Answer (score 1):

Cvs diff will compare your code against the version you currently have checked out.  (Ie, cvs diff does not show you what the differences are to what PC_A just checked in, it will only show you what files you have changed locally but not yet checked in.

cvs update will update both your local copy and the 'version' to give you any new checked in changes.  ie, what PC_A just did.  If the file hasn't been modified locally, it will update it.  If it has been modified, it will attempt to "merge" the two files together, but if it can't then it will say that the file is conflicting and you have to do it manually.